# SQL query to find substring in a column and remove certain character

Tags: sql, char, subquery, substring

I have a requirement to find substring using certain keyword based on the result i need to remove certain character in SQL

Eg. I have a column called component...I need to extract the values  after this string:

```
"^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FV"
```

Component column values:

```
^FO41,18^A0N,46,49^FDCAT.NO.^FS^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FV23 MAJOR SX^FS
^FO41,18^A0N,46,49^FDCAT.NO.^FS^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FVTest Value for 34 Inch^FS,N
```

The below query is working and giving me the half results:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(component, CHARINDEX('^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FV',component) + LEN('^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FV'), LEN(component)) AS component 
FROM 
    Equipments 
WHERE 
    Type = 'CA'
```

Result:

```
23 MAJOR SX^FS
Test Value for 34 Inch^FS,N
```

Again I need to remove everything after `^`, so my result should have the correct values

```
23 MAJOR SX
Test Value for 34 Inch
```

The below query is giving me the correct result as "23 Major SX" but it is for only one row. How can I merge these two queries so I can get the values for column which has more than 15 records

```
SELECT LEFT("23 MAJOR SX^FS", CHARINDEX('^', "23 MAJOR SX^FS") - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break up the second `SUBSTRING` portion into a `CTE` to get the remaining text required without having to overcomplicate your first `SUBSTRING` while trying to remove the `^` characters.

```
declare @equipment table (component varchar(200)) 
insert into @equipment 
values ('^FO41,18^A0N,46,49^FDCAT.NO.^FS^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FV23 MAJOR SX^FS'),
('^FO41,18^A0N,46,49^FDCAT.NO.^FS^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FVTest Value for 34 Inch^FS,N')

declare @searchString varchar(50) = '^BY5,3.0,133^FO73,324^B2N,,N,N,N^FV'

;with cte
as (
    select SUBSTRING(component, CHARINDEX(@searchString,component) + LEN(@searchString), LEN(component)) AS component 
    from @equipment
    )
select substring(component,1,CHARINDEX('^',component)-1)
from cte
```